# Redirect any domain to HTTPS and a specific path

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am looking for a piece of code that redirects any domain (wildcard ish), not just a specific domain and so that the redirect redirects to HTTPS and a specific path.

I have tried many pieces of code but pretty much 90% of the search results I could find are for redirecting specific domains.

Why do I need this? We use envoyer to deploy Statamic to our cpanel server. We use this for every single customer that we have. So for example the url for our Statamic instance is cms.example.com. I need this to be redirect to https://cms.example.com/cp but it can also be cms.totallydifferent.co.uk/cp, I can't for the life of me find a proper example.

I had the piece of code (below) running for a bit but its unreliable. It sometimes works but most of the time does not.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}cp [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

As requested the full .htaccess file:

```
SetEnv COMPOSER_HOME '/opt/cpanel/composer/bin'
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cp [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/cp [R=301,L]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
</IfModule>

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Cache-Control Headers
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------

<filesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|png|svg|woff)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000"
</filesMatch>
```

Anyone who can point me into the right direction?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

You may try this rule with 2 conditions joined with `OR` clause:

```
RewriteEngine On

# fix css/js
RewriteRule ^cp/(.+\.(?:css|js|png|jpe?g|gif))$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+cp [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cms\. [NC]
RewriteRule !\.(?:css|js|png|jpe?g|gif)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/cp [R=301,L,NC]
```

Make sure this your topmost rule and clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: Hi, This does not work, I removed the %{REQUEST_URI} bit as it was redirecting to index.php after /cp. But then I get the error of being redirected to many times.

Comment: I edited my post to include the full .htaccess

Comment: please try my updated rule as topmost rule after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: The behaviour is good. It seems to redirect properly but for some reason its destroying or not able to reach the css for the page.

Comment: To fix css/js issue add this just below `<head>` tag of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: I don't have the option to edit the head as it gets updates frequently so it would just overwrite everything. Pretty much the only thing I can edit is the .htaccess

Comment: Actually, it does not work. It keeps redirecting pretty much any url so also the api that is in the backend of the CMS.

Comment: `It keeps redirecting pretty much any url` Please provide specific example. I thought everything was working fine except for css/js as you commented earlier

Comment: I didnt know it redirected the api url also in the backend as everything was cached. The cms has a content api that pretty much goes like cms.example.com/api/xxx/xxx/xxx and that was now also being redirected to cms.example.com/cp

Comment: Yes obviously it will be redirected because there was no mention of `/api` in your question or a requirement to exclude `/api` from redirect. I suggest you to please clarify all requirements in your question instead of comments.

Comment: I thought I made it clear that just cms.example.com should be redirected to /cp as I gave 2 examples of what the url's can be. "So for example the url for our Statamic instance is cms.example.com. I need this to be redirect to https://cms.example.com/cp but it can also be cms.totallydifferent.co.uk/cp, I can't for the life of me find a proper example."

Comment: Thats not working either. And I can't have cms.example.com in the config as this changes with every single website. So thats why I need a wildcard for any url. But it should only redirect cms.testwebsite.com to cms.testwebsite.com/cp.

Comment: You mean you want to redirect any `cms.*` domain?

Comment: Yes all cms.*.* urls should be redirected to HTTPS and /cp.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229826/discussion-between-granny-and-anubhava).